# Magento Image Cache and defined constant error

Tags: error, product-images

All of a sudden, I'm getting defined constant errors when trying to view cached images.

Example image URL:

```
http://example.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/250x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/a/c/acg55001.jpg
```

Errors:

```
Notice: Constant DS already defined in app/Mage.php on line 27
Notice: Constant PS already defined in app/Mage.php on line 28
Notice: Constant BP already defined in app/Mage.php on line 29
```

From the searching I've done, this usually happens when Magento is being bootstrapped into an application that uses the same constants, or (for some reason) bootstrapped into itself.

However, as far as I know, none of that craziness is happening here. It's pretty vanilla Magento, and yet I'm suddenly getting these errors on some images.

Any ideas? I'm not really sure where to start.

**PS:** It looks like this URL path is loading `get.php` and not `index.php` so this isn't your normal page load. Still, I don't know why this is happening.

**Update:** Clearing the image cache fixed the issue, but I'd still like to find out why this happened so that I can prevent it.

**Update 2:** Not only is this reproducable, (just try to load any image that doesn't exist from the image cache,) and did not "go away on it's own," (I had to clear the cache to make it go away,) but I've also figured out the cause. I would appreciate it if moderators weren't so quick to close questions without actually reading the post.

**Answer:** Version 2.1.0 of the Extendware Full Page Cache module includes it's own autoloader at `app/code/local/Varien/Autoload.php` This includes the following at the top of the file:

```
if (defined('DS') === false) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
if (defined('PS') === false) define('PS', PATH_SEPARATOR);
if (defined('BP') === false) define('BP', dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))));
```

However, `app/Mage.php` include this:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('PS', PATH_SEPARATOR);
define('BP', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

The problem is that `get.php` first includes the `Varien/Autoload.php` (on line 59 in version 1.9.0.1) and then includes `app/Mage.php` after that (on line 96 in version 1.9.0.1.) The end result is that `Mage.php` is trying to redefine the constants. This is not an htaccess issue but is just an issue with this module.

The best solution is to have Extendware fix the issue using variables instead of these constants. (Their code is encrypted using Ioncube, so changing it myself isn't an option.)

Comment: Was anything changed in the `.htaccess`?

Comment: Not in many months.

Comment: obvious question.. does the image exist? Can you find it via FTP?

Comment: There actually wasn't even a folder at `media/catalog/product/cache` so I assumed it was doing some htaccess magic. I'll check it next time this happens though.

Comment: the `get.php` is a fallback downloader if the file doesn't exists. still, it's weird you're not getting a 404 as it should give

Comment: I have a script that removes images that are no longer associated with products. I believe that a duplicate SKU issue caused my script to delete these images. So I think you're right about hem being missing. But still, why no 404?

Comment: There must be some difference in the htaccess etc from standard Magento tho to redirect images like this